# MDAudioPlayerTableViewCell crash in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, custom-controls, ios7

i have to use `MDAudioPlayerTableViewCell` custom `tableView` cell in my iOS App.

It is working fine in iOS5 and iOS6 , But not in iOS7.

When i run it , the following error crash messages appear and crash.

```
2013-10-03 21:07:36.401 MyApp[656:60b] -[UITableViewCellScrollView drawContentView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f71390
2013-10-03 21:07:36.403 MyApp[656:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellScrollView drawContentView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f71390'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f2e6f53 0x399516af 0x2f2ea8e7 0x2f2e91d3 0x2f238598 0xc4b5f 0x31ad8001 0x31710171 0x316f99f7 0x317d286d 0x316f92ab 0x316f8f53 0x316dcc5d 0x316dc8f5 0x316dc2ff 0x316dc10f 0x316d5e3d 0x2f2b21d5 0x2f2afb79 0x2f2afebb 0x2f21ace7 0x2f21aacb 0x33ee8283 0x31abca41 0xa3c79 0xa3c00)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MDAudioPlayerTableViewCell *cell = (MDAudioPlayerTableViewCell *)[tbl dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MDAudioPlayerTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

How can i solve it for iOS7?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you have a cellview that extends UIView

```
@interface CellView : UIView

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)r;

@end
```

In your implementation you have something like this

```
@implementation CellView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r {
    [(Cell *)superview drawContentView:r];
}

@end
```

Just replace this by

```
@implementation CellView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r {
    UIView *superview = [self superview];
    if (![superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        superview = [superview superview];
    }
    [(Cell *)superview drawContentView:r];
}

@end
```

Cheers

Rui

Answer (score 0):

[UITableViewCell Internal View Hierarchy Change in iOS7](http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/646)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [(CustomCell *)[[self superview] superview] drawContentView:rect];
}
```